# Convert a long String only containing numbers into long

Tags: java, string, long-integer, typeconverter

I'm trying to convert a String(32 digits) into a long and it returns a NumberFormatException. I've tried it with Long.parseLong() and a Long object, but bone of them worked. 
code:

```
class ConvertStringToLong{
    public static void main(String in){
        long out;
        out=java.lang.Long.parseLong(in);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

i also tried

```
class ConvertStringToLong{
    public static void main(String in){
        long out;
        out = new Long(in);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the exact input string? Sounds like there's something wrong with the string

Comment: 32 digits is out of the range for a `long` (64bit signed) value

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Sounds like you need a `BigInteger` for that...

Comment: [Max long](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) value is `9223372036854775807` which has 19 digits. What value are you trying to parse?

Comment: Long max value is 19 digits. Also why did you named your method main while it does not follow the Java's main method signature  `main (String[] in)`, it is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `long` datatype is a 64-bit signed integer, so its maximum value is 2^63 - 1, which is 19 digits long. To represent larger numbers than this, you will need to use a different datatype, such as [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which allows arbitrarily large numbers. The constructor `new BigInteger(String val)` will parse a string as a BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation here (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) says that:

> BigInteger must support values in the range -2^Integer.MAX_VALUE
>   (exclusive) to +2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) and may support values
>   outside of that range. The range of probable prime values is limited
>   and may be less than the full supported positive range of BigInteger.
>   The range must be at least 1 to 2^500000000.

You can favor using a BigInteger object.